# Finding the values of the real constants such that the limit exists

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the values of the real constants $c$ and $d$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{c+dx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=\sqrt{3}$$

I really have no clue how to even get started.

Comment: Been wondering if I should do a mathematics major if I can't even comprehend a question this simple...

Comment: Start with `Series[Sqrt[c + d x], {x, 0, 1}]/x`; how to make this finite and equal to `Sqrt[3]` in the limit ?

Comment: This is more of a math question than a *Mathematica* one, so I'm migrating this to math.SE.

Comment: @J.M. I don't agree, this question is mathematically very simple, however `Mathematica` hardly tackles this problem. So I find this a valuable `Mathematica` question and upvoted it.

Comment: @Artes, considering the "I realised I posted on the wrong forum" comment...

Comment: @J.M. I haven't seen that comment, nevetheless `Limit` would be smarter and this makes the question `Mathematica`lly interesting.

Comment: Below, I've posted an intelligent asnwer as opposed to a mathematica software answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way Mathematica is going to solve that directly for you, but it can help you understand what happens. First, let's ask it what the general expression for the limit is:

```
Limit[(Sqrt[c + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, x -> 0]
```

The answer is:

```
DirectedInfinity[-Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[c]]
```

So, this limit is an infinity, and has the same sign as $\sqrt c-\sqrt 3$. If you want the limit to be finite, you have only one special case you can try: what happens if $\sqrt c-\sqrt 3=0$, i.e. if $c=3$?

```
Limit[(Sqrt[3 + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, x -> 0]
```

The results is:

```
d/(2 Sqrt[3])
```

which is finite, so all is well. Now, you need this to be equal to $\sqrt 3$, which you can sure solve yourself, but just to be thorough, let's ask Mathematica to do it:

```
Solve[Limit[(Sqrt[3 + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, x -> 0] == Sqrt[3], d]
```

---

**Conclusion:** no silver bullet, but definitely a way to help you understand this equation if your math skills fail you!

Comment: Thanks F'x. You have been an amazing help with the pictures in my questions. I realised I posted on the wrong forum w/e. Thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Method I**

Since we have a fraction going to a non-vanishing value given its denominator is going to `0` we have to assume that its numerator also tends to `0`, therefore we should solve :

```
Reduce[Limit[Numerator[(Sqrt[c + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x], x -> 0] == 0, {c, d}]
```

> ```
> c == 3
> ```

We could use `Solve` as well with the option : `InverseFunctions -> True`, now taking the value into the system we have :

```
Reduce[ c == 3 && Limit[(Sqrt[3 + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, x -> 0] == Sqrt[3], {c, d}]
```

> ```
> c == 3 && d == 6
> ```

**Method II**

Another way to tackle the problem is to expand the expression in a power series around `x == 0` :

```
Normal @ Series[ (Sqrt[c + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Now you can find limits of every term separately :

```
Limit[#, x -> 0] & /@ List @@ Normal@Series[(Sqrt[c + d*x] - Sqrt[3])/x, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> {d/(2 Sqrt[c]), (-Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[c]) Infinity, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

The only problem comes from the second term, however we can get rid of it by assuming a priori its value by setting `c == 3` or simply solving this system :

```
Solve[ {( -Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[c])/x == 0,  d/(2 Sqrt[c]) == Sqrt[3]}, {c, d}, 
         InverseFunctions -> True]
```

> ```
>  {{c -> 3, d -> 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{c+dx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=\sqrt{3}$$

Since the denominator goes to $0$, the limit cannot exist unless the numerator also goes to $0$.  The numerator is $\sqrt{c+dx}-\sqrt{3}$, so that would have to go to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$.  But it goes to $\sqrt{c+d\cdot0} - \sqrt{3}$.  Hence $c+d\cdot0$ must be $3$.  That tells you $c$ is $3$, and you've got
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{3+dx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=\sqrt{3}.$$

Now rationalize the numerator:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3+dx}-\sqrt{3}}{x} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{3+dx}-\sqrt{3}\right)\left(\sqrt{3+dx}+\sqrt{3}\right)}{x\left(\sqrt{3+dx}+\sqrt{3}\right)}=  \frac{dx}{x\left(\sqrt{3+dx}+\sqrt{3}\right)}.
$$
The $x$s cancel and we get
$$
\frac{d}{\sqrt{3+dx}+\sqrt{3}}.
$$
The limit of that as $x\to0$ is $d/(2\sqrt{3})$.  So you want $d/(2\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3}$.  Multiply both sides by $2\sqrt{3}$ and you get $d=6$.